# fancyhdr: Footer not centered after changing page geometry

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fancyhdr, geometry

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{something centered in footer}
\lhead{\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
A normal page.

\clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=.5in,includeheadfoot,hcentering}
\lipsum[1-2]

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}

\end{document}
```

## Problem

As is shown in the MWE, the footer is not centered on the second page, after the geometry has been changed. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: I'd say it's perfectly normal. Why are you changing the page geometry after one page? If your aim is to have a different geometry for the title page, then change geometry for that and restore the normal one afterwards.

Comment: @egreg: I want to fit a figure that is slightly too wide for a portray page and too long for a landscape page. The figure is already scaled and I don't want to scale it further for legibility concerns. So my solution was to decrease the left/right margins, which led to the above problem.

Comment: `\newgeometry` is not the answer; you can simply insert the image in a `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` possibly adding some space in the box to position the image as you wish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will force it to the center:

```
\cfoot{\makebox[\textwidth][c]{something centered in footer}}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\makebox[\textwidth][c]{something centered in footer}}
\lhead{\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
A normal page.

\clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=.5in,includeheadfoot,hcentering}
\lipsum[1-2]

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]